# jwplayer - detecting the start

Tags: events, click, jwplayer

I am trying to detect a start click in jwplayer. I am embedding it via swfobject so the method is slightly different from the example in the api, http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16024/listening-for-player-events

I have tried

```
var flashvars = {
    'file':'xxx',
    'streamer':'xxxxxx',
'image':'xxxxx',
'plugins':'xxxxx',
'gapro.accountid':'xxxx',
'gapro.trackstarts':'xxxx',
'gapro.trackpercentage':'xxxx',
'gapro.tracktime':'xxxx',
'logo.file':'xxxxx',
'logo.link':'xxxx',
'logo.hide':'xxxx',
'logo.position':'xxxx'
```

};

```
jwplayer().onPlay(function() {alert('it has started'});
```

jwplayer() is not defined, how do I defined an object to detect the click?

Answer (score 7):

The player is probably undefined because it hasn't been created yet. You should wrap your command in a callback from a DOM ready listener. Since you're using jQuery you can use its .ready() method ([jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jwplayer().onPlay(function() { alert('it has started'); });
});
```

Just a note about jwplayer onPlay(), it doesn't necessarily happen from a click event, it fires whenever the video is played, which could be by clicking play, or by programmatically playing the video. All it's telling you is that the video is playing. (Corrected the syntax error)

Comment: This event can fire multiple times when video is paused and started again, it will fire again.